# How to parse files larger than 100GB in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, large-files

I have text files with about 100 Gb size with the below format (with duplicate records of line and ips and domains) :

```
domain|ip 
yahoo.com|89.45.3.5
bbc.com|45.67.33.2
yahoo.com|89.45.3.5
myname.com|45.67.33.2
etc.
```

I am trying to parse them using the following python code but I still get Memory error. Does anybody know a more optimal way of parsing such files? (Time is an important element for me)

```
files = glob(path)
for filename in files:
    print(filename)
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            try:
                domain = line.split('|')[0]
                ip = line.split('|')[1].strip('\n')
                if ip in d:
                    d[ip].add(domain)
                else:
                    d[ip] = set([domain])
            except:
                print (line)
                pass

    print("this file is finished")

for ip, domains in d.iteritems():
    for domain in domains:
        print("%s|%s" % (ip, domain), file=output)
```

Comment: Indent your final for loop so its inside the outer for loop.

Comment: You're going to have to batch process it. You're creating a dictionary of domains and ip addresses which presumably is going to be on the same level of memory size as the file itself. Meaning unless you've got ~100 GB of RAM you're going to struggle.

Comment: You can create pool of workers by `multiprocessing.pool` and map through list of files. So each file will be handled by it's own worker.

Comment: First though! Divide the lines to different intervals, then do it this way (every 10K lines as an example, periodically)

Comment: of course you do, since you are building ridiculously big monstrosity called "d", while yo need to embrace a way different approach. I commited small blog entry on how to refactor old code like this: http://x20x.co.uk/2014/10/tutorial-upcycling-legacy-code-into-scalable-service-part-1/

Comment: Well, we are all jumping to a lot of hasty conclusions about the behavior of  `d.__setitem__` which isn't specified here...

Comment: @ChrisMartin if it was what you are hinting, he wouldn't have memory issues ;)

Comment: Why do you need to put the data in a dictionary? Can't you just append to files with domains as filenames? `with open(domain,'a') as f1: f1.write(ip)`. If a domain already exists, the file will be appended. Otherwise, a new file will be created. Later, you can just walk through the created files. (No need to `strip('\n')` in this case.)

Comment: @ssm: the OP is also filtering out duplicates here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python objects take a little more memory than the same value does on disk; there is a little overhead in a reference count, and in sets there is also the cached hash value per value to consider.

Don't read all those objects into (Python) memory; use a database instead. Python comes with a library for the SQLite database, use that to convert your file to a database. You can then build your output file from that:

```
import csv
import sqlite3
from itertools import islice

conn = sqlite3.connect('/tmp/ipaddresses.db')
conn.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ipaddress (domain, ip)')
conn.execute('''\
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS domain_ip_idx 
    ON ipaddress(domain, ip)''')

for filename in files:
    print(filename)
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        while True:
            with conn:
                batch = list(islice(reader, 10000))
                if not batch:
                    break
                cursor.executemany(
                    'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ipaddress VALUES(?, ?)',
                    batch)

conn.execute('CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ip_idx ON ipaddress(ip)')
with open(outputfile, 'wb') as outfh:
    writer = csv.writer(outfh, delimiter='|')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT ip, domain from ipaddress order by ip')
    writer.writerows(cursor)
```

This handles your input data in batches of 10000, and produces an index to sort on *after* inserting. Producing the index is going to take some time, but it'll all fit in your available memory.

The `UNIQUE` index created at the start ensures that only unique domain - ip address pairs are inserted (so only unique domains per ip address are tracked); the `INSERT OR IGNORE` statement skips any pair that is already present in the database.

Short demo with just the sample input you gave:

```
>>> import sqlite3
>>> import csv
>>> import sys
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> conn = sqlite3.connect('/tmp/ipaddresses.db')
>>> conn.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ipaddress (domain, ip)')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x106c62730>
>>> conn.execute('''\
...     CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS domain_ip_idx 
...     ON ipaddress(domain, ip)''')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x106c62960>
>>> reader = csv.reader('''\
... yahoo.com|89.45.3.5
... bbc.com|45.67.33.2
... yahoo.com|89.45.3.5
... myname.com|45.67.33.2
... '''.splitlines(), delimiter='|')
>>> cursor = conn.cursor()
>>> while True:
...     with conn:
...         batch = list(islice(reader, 10000))
...         if not batch:
...             break
...         cursor.executemany(
...             'INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ipaddress VALUES(?, ?)',
...             batch)
... 
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x106c62810>
>>> conn.execute('CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS ip_idx ON ipaddress(ip)')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x106c62960>
>>> writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, delimiter='|')
>>> cursor = conn.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute('SELECT ip, domain from ipaddress order by ip')
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x106c627a0>
>>> writer.writerows(cursor)
45.67.33.2|bbc.com
45.67.33.2|myname.com
89.45.3.5|yahoo.com
```

Comment: @user2058811: it does now. The unique index prevents domain - ipaddress pairs that already exist from being inserted again; the `INSERT OR IGNORE` will just move to the next pair in that case.

Comment: I have never worked with sqlite before but not sure why getting this: "sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 26 supplied" cuz now I am only splitting each line into two sections(ip,domain)

Comment: @user2058811: you are passing in a single string, where the `execute()` action expects a list of two elements instead.

Comment: @user2058811: I made a few small mistakes (I wrote the code off the cuff on the train); corrected and sample demo added.

Comment: Thanks. But I still get the same error (my input files are text files not csv) and I am using this instead of your suggestion:files = glob(path)
for filename in files:
    print(filename)
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        for line in f:
            reader = line.strip('\n').split('|')

Comment: @user2058811: I am using the csv module to parse your text files. CSV stands for 'character-separated values' here. Note the `delimiter='|'`.

Comment: @user2058811: by having the `csv` module split out your lines the code is *vastly* simplified, but it handles the *exact same input* your code handled.

Comment: Thanks Martij your are helping a lot. I am not sure why yours is working and mine not cuz they seem identical. I still get this error: cursor.executemany('INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ip_address VALUES(?, ?)', batch)
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 2, and there are 4 supplied.

Comment: @user2058811: your file has rows with more than two columns. You may need to post-process those; you could pass in `(r[:2] for r in batch)` instead of `batch` there. That's a generator expression selecting just the first 2 columns of each row.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63499/discussion-between-user2058811-and-martijn-pieters).

Comment: Since I have lines with more that two arrays, how can I put an exception for reader to get those line that has only two arrays and not more?

Comment: @user2058811: you can filter the reader rows: instead of passing in `batch` to `executemany()`, pass in `(r for r in batch if len(r) == 2)`.

Answer (score 3):

A different, simpler, solution might be using the `sort(1)` utility:

```
sort input -u -t\| -k2 -T . --batch-size=50 --buffer-size=1G > output
```

This will sort the file by the second column, where columns are separated by a `|`; `-T` sets the directory for temporary files to the current directory, the default is `/tmp/`, which is often a memory device. The `-u` flag removes duplicates, and the other flags may (or may not...) increase performance.

I tested this with a 5.5GB file, and that took ~200 seconds on my laptop; I don't know how well that ranks vs. the other solutions posted. You may also get better performance with a different `--batch-size` or `--buffer-size`.

In any case, this is certainly the simplest solution as it requires no programming at all :)

Comment: The problem is that I with this method I will only get one ip and the associated domain, while what I want is ip and all of its associated domains, like lines with ip and unique domain in each line (ip can be repeated)

Comment: @user2058811 Right. You can still use this command (minus the `-u` flag) to sort the entries by IP address, processing the output of that with either a shell script or Python script is quite easy, since you don't need to fetch the entire file (just the entries grouped by IP)...

Answer (score 1):

Before thinking of using multiprocessing, I would divide the lines to different intervals.

- Calculate the number of lines inside the file

> ```
>   l= len(files.readlines())
>   #l= sum(1 for _ in files)
> ```

Then, divide Your work to different stages, and process the data taking in cosideration two things:

1. Load/Store your data to file (Use DB, CVS, Json ..) whatever you find it useful.
2. Divide the data processing work to different stages, increment the number of lines you process every-time until you finish the work (to reuse the code you wrote);

nbrIterations= l // step

- Pack the code inside a function giving a number interval, and increment it everytime.

> ```
>  def dataProcessing(numberOfLine) :
> ```

```
    if (numberOfLine>l):
        print("this file is finished")
        return False
    else: 

        files = glob(path)
        for filename in files:
            print(filename)
            with open(filename) as f:
                for line in f:
                    if line>numberOfLine and line numberOfLine<numberOfLine+step:

                        domain = line.split('|')[0]
                        ip = line.split('|')[1].strip('\n')
                        if ip in d:
                            d[ip].add(domain)
                        else:
                            d[ip] = set([domain])

                    for ip, domains in d.iteritems():
                        for domain in domains:
                            # Better to store it in another file (or load to DB) using Pandas(load it to CSV) or DB Connector to load it to DB
                            print("%s|%s" % (ip, domain), file=output)
        return True
```

- define your "step" so you can go through the lines of file

> ```
> while dataProcessing(numberOfLine): 
>   numberOfLine+=step
> ```

Your second option is to explore the possibilities with multipocessing (it depends on your machine performance).