# How to parse a bunch of large text files (100Gb each)?

Tags: python, parsing, sorting, bigdata

I have 30 very large text files with  two column in them (domain|ip) with a lot of duplicates of records. What I ultimately want is unique domains per ip. This is how a file looks like:

```
man.bia.com|23.45.33.3
to.biaa.co.uk|23.45.33.3
man.bia.com|23.45.33.3
yahoo.com|34.55.44.2
yahoo.com|56.55.37.67
```

I have already tried solutions suggested before like sqlite but it was not appropriate beacuse it would take a lot of time for each file to be parsed.
[How to parse files larger than 100GB in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26503199/how-to-parse-files-larger-than-100gb-in-python?noredirect=1#comment41640994_26503199)

Does anybody have any suggestions for parsing such a large dataset in limited time with limited memory?

Comment: are the files sorted?

Comment: @ch3ka no I cannot see any pattern

Comment: sort by ip (as in one answer of the other question, without the `-u` flag so you get all domains for the ips), then you can process the file in O(n) execution time and O(1) memory space.

Comment: This seems more like a sorting problem than a parsing problem. Have you tried the standard sort utility? eg. `sort -t'|' -k2 -k1,1 -u files`?

Comment: @ch3ka I also have duplicate lines and I don't think without -u that could be solved. what do you mean by is O(n) and O(1)?

Comment: `O()` means complexity class - basically, what I say means "will take a while (but not too long) since the files are big, and will use virtually no memory". If you have duplicate lines, eliminate them. That's no problem when files are sorted.

Comment: @ch3ka they are not sorted

Comment: well.. sort them, then?

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
sort -t'|' -k2 -k1,1 files
```

followed by this python code

```
current_ip = 0
domain_tracking = []
with open(output, 'w') as fout:
    for filename in files:
        with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='|')
            for domain, ip in reader:
                domain_tracking.append(domain)
                if ip == current_ip:
                    pass
                else:
                    fout.write(ip + '|' + ','.join(set(domain_tracking))))
                    current_ip = ip
                    domain_tracking = []
```

This is just going through your ordered files and writing every ip only once followed by one domain in case is only one, or many domains in case there are repetitions, the footprint in memory is minimal.

Comment: thanks . Do you mean that run the bash command first on all of the files  and then run the python code on the sorted ones? Can you make your bash command more explicit in terms of output and input files?

Comment: I am not an expert of this command, check the manual, you can try `sort input1 input2 input3 -t\| -k2 . > output`

Answer (score 0):

Sorting can take a really long for big files, I would try pure Python solution with `dict` and `set`:

```
import collections
import fileinput

results = collections.defaultdict(set)

for line in fileinput.input():
    try:
        domain, ip = line.strip().split('|')
    except ValueError:
        continue
    results[ip].add(domain)
print results # or write to file or anything
```

This has complexity O(n), and only IO will be bottleneck here.
Don't worry about memory unless you really hit the wall - this is what swap partition is for, right?

If your result set is extremely large (mostly unique pairs), and swapping takes really to long, you can run this script on smaller batches, writing partial results (that fit into memory better) to file buckets (each range of IP to separate file). Then you can use another script to parse each of those buckets separately.